# How to pagination in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a script of pagination. When I run, it show the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\folder\index.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\folder\index.php on line 12
```

Here's my script:

```
<?php
include 'db.inc.php';
$per_page = 2;

$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT 'id' FROM 'names'");
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query,0) /$per_page);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT 'name' FROM 'names' LIMIT $start, $per_page");
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo '<p>', $query_row['name'],'</p>';
}
if($pages >=1 && $page <= $pages){
for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){
echo  ($x == $page) ? '<strong> <a href="?page='.$X.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$X.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
}
}
?>
```

At last i found my problem. It was for $X.
The correct is:

```
echo  ($number == $page) ? '<strong> <a href="?page='.$number.'">'.$number.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$number.'">'.$number.'</a> ';
```

Comment: Do you always demand people solve your problem?

Comment: How does one select anything from a string? Use grave accents (`) instead of apostrophes (').

Comment: You shoudn't use mysql_* functions. You should use http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to debug your script and use `mysql_error()`. Then fix your sql errors.

It will then become obvious that example `count 'id'` should be `count(id)`

Comment: You didn't read the OP's script carefully & solve the problem. He may get mad.

Comment: I get that there may be a language barrier, but it seems as though the OP thinks that monkeys sit in front of computers and answer questions for people.

Answer (score 0):

The error `mysql_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` is usually an indicator that your MySQL query contains some error.

One obvious syntax error is that in your queries, you should use a grave accent instead of a quote around column and table names. (Grave accents are these: `. Found at the top left of most English keyboards)